# Destiny vs Efforts

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma

As per shrimad bhagwat geeta, everyone should do their respective karmas and putting their efforts and do not focus on outcome.

Now I am asking my question through a scenario.

If my wallet is stolen then,

1) Should I think that it's result of previously charged karmas?

2) Should I need to put efforts to find wallet? If yes then how much efforts I need to put to satisfy karma theory?

3) Should I need to happy that I have tried to find it for 2 days and  now everything on 'niyati'.(destiny a fix state of situation in which we can't do anything)

As per my understanding that I just do karma(try to find it) and do not think about outcome(whether I will get it or not)

I am not sure  how much efforts are required like If I find it 2 days and if  I not get it so I have dilemma that if I find it another 2 days then may be chance to get it back or I should stop my efforts.

Thanks in advance for reading this question and your guidance.

Comment: This sounds primary opinion based.

Comment: @Ravi THe sentence you removed is not opinion based. Let it be.

Comment: @SreeCharan: thanks for reading question and I have added removed sentence.

Comment: You should obviously try to find the wallet of course..haha..Whats there to ask?

Comment: Are you asking whether Nishkama Karma will work or not?

Comment: This will help you understand reality https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fscvOuOPjGc

Comment: @ Rickrodss: of course bro but where to stop? That's the question.